# Как я могу изменить фоновый цвет элемента помещённого в RecyclerView в зависимости от свойства класса?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, recyclerview

Как я могу изменить фоновый цвет элемента ( розовый на картинке ) помещённого в RecyclerView в зависимости от свойства класса?
Класс адаптера:

```
public class CountingEntry_Adapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<CountingEntry_Adapter.ViewHolder>
{
    interface OnStateClickListener
    {
        void onStateClick(CountingEntry state, int position);
    }
    private final LayoutInflater inflater;
    private final List<CountingEntry> entryList;
    private final OnStateClickListener onClickListener;

    public CountingEntry_Adapter(Context context, List<CountingEntry> entries_, OnStateClickListener onClickListener)
    {
        this.onClickListener = onClickListener;
        this.entryList = entries_;
        this.inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    }
    @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.O)
    @Override
    public CountingEntry_Adapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType)
    {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, parent, false);
        return new ViewHolder(view);
    }

    @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.O)
    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(CountingEntry_Adapter.ViewHolder holder, int position)
    {
        CountingEntry Entry = entryList.get(position);
        holder.purchase.setText(Entry.GetPurchase());
        holder.cost.setText(String.valueOf(Entry.GetCost()));
        holder.dateofpurchase.setText(Entry.GetDateOfPurchase().toString());
        holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view)
            {
                onClickListener.onStateClick(Entry, position);
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount()
    {
        return entryList.size();
    }

    @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.O)
    public static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder
    {
        final TextView purchase;
        final TextView cost;
        final TextView dateofpurchase;
        ViewHolder(View view)
        {
            super(view);
            purchase = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textviewlist_purchase);
            cost = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textviewlist_cost);
            dateofpurchase = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textviewlist_dataofpurchase);
        }
    }
}
Объект класса отображаемый в RecyclerViewpackage com.example.personalaccounting;

import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Parcel;
import android.os.Parcelable;

import androidx.annotation.RequiresApi;

import java.time.LocalDate;

@RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.O)
public class CountingEntry implements Parcelable, Comparable<CountingEntry>
{
    private String purchase;
    private int cost;
    private LocalDate dateOfpurchase;
    private boolean isIncome; //исходя из этого поля хочу менять фоновый цвет одной записи в RecyclerView
    public void SetPurchase(String purchase_)
    {
        purchase = purchase_;
    }
    public void SetCost(int cost_)
    {
        cost = cost_;
    }
    public void SetDateOfPurchase(LocalDate dateOfpurchase_)
    {
        dateOfpurchase = dateOfpurchase_;
    }
    public String GetPurchase()
    {
        return purchase;
    }
    public int GetCost()
    {
        return cost;
    }
    public LocalDate GetDateOfPurchase()
    {
        return dateOfpurchase;
    }
    public String GetDateOfPurchaseAsString()
    {
        return dateOfpurchase.toString();
    }
    public void SetIsIncome(boolean value)
    {
        this.isIncome = value;
    }
    public boolean GetIsIncome()
    {
        return isIncome;
    }
    public CountingEntry(String purchase_,int cost_,LocalDate dateOfpurchase_, boolean isIncome_)
    {
        this.purchase = purchase_;
        this.cost = cost_;
        this.dateOfpurchase = dateOfpurchase_;
        this.isIncome = isIncome_;
    }
    public CountingEntry()
    {
        this.purchase = "empty";
        this.cost = 0;
        this.dateOfpurchase = LocalDate.now();
        this.isIncome = false;
    }
    @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.Q)
    private CountingEntry(Parcel in)
    {
        purchase = in.readString();
        cost = in.readInt();
        dateOfpurchase = LocalDate.parse(in.readString());
        isIncome = in.readBoolean();
    }

    @Override
    public int describeContents()
    {
        return 0;
    }

    @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.Q)
    @Override
    public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags)
    {
        dest.writeString(this.purchase);
        dest.writeInt(this.cost);
        dest.writeString(this.dateOfpurchase.toString());
        dest.writeBoolean(this.isIncome);
    }
    public static final Parcelable.Creator<CountingEntry> CREATOR = new Parcelable.Creator<CountingEntry>()
    {
        @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.Q)
        public CountingEntry createFromParcel(Parcel in)
        {
            return new CountingEntry(in);
        }

        public CountingEntry[] newArray(int size)
        {
            return new CountingEntry[size];
        }
    };

    @Override
    public int compareTo(CountingEntry obj)
    {
        return (int) (this.dateOfpurchase.toEpochDay() - obj.dateOfpurchase.toEpochDay());
    }
}


[![введите сюда описание изображения][1]][1]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/23dYl.png
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Решил так
 public void onBindViewHolder(CountingEntry_Adapter.ViewHolder holder, int position)
    {
        CountingEntry Entry = entryList.get(position);
        holder.purchase.setText(Entry.GetPurchase());
        holder.cost.setText(String.valueOf(Entry.GetCost()));
        holder.dateofpurchase.setText(Entry.GetDateOfPurchase().toString());
        if(Entry.GetIsIncome())
        {
           holder.itemView.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);
        }
        else if(!Entry.GetIsIncome())
        {
           holder.itemView.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
        }
        holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view)
            {
                onClickListener.onStateClick(Entry, position);
            }
        });
    }
```